# Is there a way to binary patch WAR files?

Tags: diff, war

My web application is getting bigger and bigger, now is 25Mb. I have to upload it everytime and takes a while with my DSL. I was thinking of using a binary patch system, but I can't find a good one. Requirements:

- Work on Linux and Windows
- (Desired) be available on Amazon Ec2 linux via yum
- Easy to integrate in scripts

Suggestions? Alternative ways of doing this?

Comment: Try [Googling it](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=binary+diff). There are quite a few binary diff utilities.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that a war file is nothing more than a zip file, my guess is that tiny little changes to one file could potentially modify the whole binary (such is the nature of compression) so binary patching really doesn't make sense since you might be sending the whole thing each time anyway.

Instead may I suggest that you simply explode the war file and use something like rsync to keep the contents up to date? I'd think this would be less of a headache while accomplishing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux: bsdiff/bspatch

The bsdiff package is also available under cygwin.